# React is rendering before it receives the data, even if I try to check it before rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

in my startup i load a few variables into my global store in Redux, including populating an array called "outputList"

in one of my components, when I run it, even if I try to error check for data before rendering, it still flashes red in error while loading stating:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Once it receives the data 1 or 2 seconds later, then it loads properly.  Obviously this isn't acceptable.  The API it's receiving data from is synchronous as well.

In my component I have the following.  it shows "it worked!" only after the browser flashes in error yelling that property length undefined message.

How can i fix this?  thank you for any help

```
renderContent() {
  if (this.props.outputList.length > 0) {
    return (<span>it worked!</span>);
  }
  else {
    return (<span>did not work</span>);
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    {this.renderContent()}
  );
}
```

EDIT:

in renderContent() i added a console.log(this.props.outputList) as requested.  i get 2 logs

first log: an empty array
second log: a populated array

sorry i dont think u really need me to post actual array data do u?

Comment: Please output your `this.props.outputList` property and update it into your question.

Comment: Change your if condition to if (this.props.outputList != undefined)

Comment: @MattYao wow that worked.... sigh.  long day.  thank you.  put an official answer and i'll give you credit

Comment: I am glad to help and I have posted a better answer as you requested :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very common issue for React dev due to the asyc request happening during the component lifecycle.

A very easy solution is to define the condition in your render() which decides when to render the actual body of content:

```
render(){
  if(!this.props || this.props.data == undefined){
    return null; //You can change here to put a customized loading spinner 
  }

  return(
    <div className="container">{this.props.data}</div>
  );
}
```

Here this.props.data is fetched from redux asyc functions.